# background doesn't change when i edit it with js

Tags: javascript, html, sass

when i change the background color from a div with js its doenst change it on my site.
when i inspect i see that the css gets added inline but it doenst change
this is the code i use in my js file to change the backgroundcolor
i also make the div in this file
i also have to ue js and setattribute because its for school task
here is the whole js file

```
const div=document.createElement("div")
const h3=document.createElement("h3")
document.querySelector("main").appendChild(div)
div.appendChild(h3)
h3.innerHTML="Status"
div.id="status"
```

here i initiate the div

```
document.getElementById("status").addEventListener("mouseover", () => document.getElementById("status").setAttribute("style", "background-color:black;"));
document.getElementById("status").addEventListener("mouseout", () => document.getElementById("status").removeAttribute("style"));
```

here i try to change the background color

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>My Games</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script tpye="text/javascript" src="js/dom.js" defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/table-overview.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="Logo image of games" class="logo" />
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li class="actual">
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="overview.html">Overview</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="table-overview.html">Table overview</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
      <h2>My Games</h2>
    </main>
    <footer>Wietse Gijbels: Front-end - 2022</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
*{
    background-color: #00004f;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
}

h2{
    margin: 2em 0 ;
}

h3{
    margin: 3em 0 1.5em 0
}

p{
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

footer{
    margin-top: 2em;
    background-color: #000083;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Where is `div` come from ?

Comment: Not sure if `setAttribute` is a good choice for this, try `div.style.backgroundColor = 'black'` instead. (And set `transparent` if you want to remove it again.) And btw., why use JS for what is really rather CSS' job to begin with?

Comment: its for a school exercise so i have to do it this way with setattribute and js

Comment: You need to post a minimal reproducable example as this is just a big ol mess to read through.

Comment: @WietseGijbels Can you add the related html code? Where is `main` come from?

Comment: @WietseGijbels Quit that school. It’s doing you more harm than good.

Comment: @user3840170 lol just first years cours so learning in steps starting from nothing kinda anoying i know next year they will prob just say forget last year now we will do it the right way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your code, we did not see where is `div` come from.

If we defined an element and assign it to `div`,it will work,below is a simple reference for you

```js
let div = document.getElementById("status")
div.addEventListener("mouseover", () => div.setAttribute("style", "background-color:black;color:white"));
div.addEventListener("mouseout", () => div.removeAttribute("style"));
```

```html
<div id="status">Change Background Color</div>
```

---

Update: Based on OP's new code

```js
const div=document.createElement("div")
const h3=document.createElement("h3")
document.querySelector("main").appendChild(div)
div.appendChild(h3)
h3.innerHTML="Status"
div.id="status"

let divEle = document.getElementById("status")
divEle.addEventListener("mouseover", () => divEle.setAttribute("style", "background-color:black;color:white"));
divEle.addEventListener("mouseout", () => divEle.removeAttribute("style"));
```

```html
<main>
</main>
```

Comment: still have the same problem when i inspect the site and hover over the div is see this   <div id="status" style="background-color:black;"

Comment: @WietseGijbels You need to post a minimal reproducable example so that others can help you analysis it

Comment: is this what u mean

Comment: @WietseGijbels I have updated my answer,you can check it again.

Comment: still the same it shows it inline when i inspect but it doesnt change could this bc of some of my sass is overriding the js or should that not give a problem

Answer (score -1):

I don't really know whats going on here with your current code however I wrote the following to get the desired result.

```js
const div = document.createElement("div")

var body = document.getElementById("main")
body.appendChild(div)
div.setAttribute("id", "status");

let divSelect = document.getElementById("main")
divSelect.addEventListener("mouseover", () => div.setAttribute("style", "background-color:black;color:white"));
divSelect.addEventListener("mouseout", () => div.removeAttribute("style"));
```

```css
#status {
  width: 200px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```